# Delphi - Alexandria - Generate Android App Bundle file not found in Options

Tags: android, delphi, bundle, generate

I'm using Alexandria (RAD Studio 11.1) but when I try to configure my Android 64 bit project in the Options > Building > Delphi Compiler > Compiling options. After select "All configurations - Android 64-bit platform" as the active target, I don't found in the "Other options" the "Generate Android App Bundle file (arm + arm64)".
In the online manual at this link:

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Submitting_Your_Android_App_to_Google_Play

there is also an image showing this option, but in my delphi it is not present!
This option instead is present in 10.4.1.
Without this option it is not possible to have an .aab file to upload to the Google Play Console.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The value you're looking for has a slightly different name in Alexandria:

*"Generate Android 32-bit and 64-bit binaries (armeabi-v7a + arm64-v8a)"*

Once built, you'll find your bundle in

*ProjectName\Android64\Release\ProjectName\bin\ProjectName.aab*